# Why does using this closing line of code does not work?

Tags: excel, vba

The code stops at the following line working because of the following line

```
objExcel.Workbooks("cde.XLSX").close
```

The code properly downloads data from SAP and save it as "cde.xlsx" in a folder location. Once the saving is processed the file opens up by itself and the code is supposed to close it.
The closing step does not to work.
It used to work, did not change anything in the code.

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objSheet, lastrowRow, i
Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.Workbooks("Extract_zrep.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set lien = objExcel.Workbooks("Extract_zrep.xlsm")
lastrow = objSheet.Range("B65536").End(-4162).Row

SaveToFolder = objSheet.Cells(5, 5).Value
Date1 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(2, 6).Value))
Date2 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(2, 8).Value))
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nZMM_xxxx"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").text = ""
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").text = "USER"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").text = "CDE"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = SaveToFolder
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "cde.XLSX"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 3
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
objExcel.Workbooks("cde.XLSX").close
```

[image]

Comment: Please, show us the rest of the relevant conde. Where `objExcel` has been declared and set? Is there in that Excel session a workbook named "cde.XLSX"?

Comment: Most likely the workbook is opened in a different instance of excel.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458926/vba-is-sometimes-not-recognizing-excel-file-that-has-been-opened-through-sap-gui

Comment: Do you know the full path of "cde.XLSX" workbook? Saying **save it as "cde.xlsx" in a folder location** makes me supposing that the answer is yes. Am I right?

Comment: Did you get any errors? If so which one? Do you have any `On Error Resume Next` lines in that code? If so remove them and then tell us which errors you get and in which line.

Comment: I also edited my answer code. You may keep your found open session in the way your existing code does and my suggestion will only find the **real** Excel session, where the workbook in discussion is open and process it as you need. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**:

If you know the workbook in discussion full name, as I suppose, please replace that not working code line with the next code:

```
  Dim objEx As Object, wbFullName As String
   
  wbFullName "C:\your real path\cde.XLSX" 'please, use the real folder path!
  Set objEx = GetObject(wbFullName).Application
  objEx.Workbooks("cde.XLSX").close
  objEx.Quit
```

It will find and close the new Excel Session, where the workbook is open, close the workbook and quit session...